# Why can't we define main function in static inner classes?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have the following simple code

```
public class Tester {
    static class TesterChild {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            System.out.println("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles fine. But when I run it I get the following Error

```
[aniket@localhost src]$ java Tester
Error: Could not find or load main class Tester
```

Question is why can't we define our main method in static inner class?

Update1 :

As specified in the answers/comments I have change the code to following

```
public class Tester {
    public static class TesterChild {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            System.out.println("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

I compiled it and it made two class files `Tester.class` and `Tester$TesterChild.class`. But still i am getting error

```
[aniket@localhost Desktop]$ java Tester$TesterChild
Error: Could not find or load main class Test
```

Update 2:

Ok now I included current directory in the classpath and executed still getting error

```
[aniket@localhost Desktop]$ java -cp . Tester$TesterChild
Error: Main method not found in class Tester, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args
```

Comment: Your main class is not `Tester`, but `Tester.TesterChild`. I'd make it public as well (it's probably a requirement).

Comment: its working fine for me. Tried in both eclipse and command prompt.

Comment: Same here. OP may have some other problem which is not present in his example.

Comment: Working fine in my Intellij IDEA but having problem in CLI execution.

Comment: @Aniket Thakur updated my answer to resolve the issue.Please look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be run as `main` but you are not using the right class. Your main class is not `Tester` but `Tester.TesterChild`.

In Eclipse it will run without any setup but from the command line you have to use the `java 'yourpackage.Tester$TesterChild'` syntax as others mentioned above.

You need to wrap the name of your class in `''`s because on linux/unix the shell might think that `$TesterChild` is a variable. If you try it out in the prompt you will get something like this if you omit the `''`s:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Tester

If you need to explicitly set the classpath you can use the `-cp` or the `-classpath` option or you can set it from the commandline: `set CLASSPATH=/somedir`

Answer (score 1):

Since you have defined `main()` method in inner class.
Run the inner class to get `main()` to be executed.

use command line `java Tester$TesterChild`.
**update**
I think you are placing java file in some package.If then use this command line.

`java -cp . yourPackageName.Tester$TesterChild`
For example I have placed file in a package named `test`.Then my command is like this

`java -cp . test.Tester$TesterChild`

Answer (score 1):

Beware that the dollar sign has special meaning to most shells. I.e. if you write
`java -cp . Tester$TesterChild` your shell might replace `$TesterChild` with the contents of an environment variable with that name or silently replace it with nothing if it doesn’t exist. Try `java -cp . 'Tester$TesterChild'` or `java -cp . Tester\$TesterChild`